# image-rendering DOM equivalent

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, dom

What's the DOM equivalent of the `image-rendering` CSS property in Firefox? i.e. is there a way to set it aside from doing `element.style.cssText = "image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;"`?

Note: browser compatibility is not an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In firefox 4.0rc1 I can use

```
element.style.imageRendering = "-moz-crisp-edges";
```

without problems.

Like with any other css property just switch from hyphen-lowercase to camelCase.

Comment: just curious: can you see it in the DOM tab in Firebug?